# Rust Arc how to get_mut and after that restore ability to read by other copies of the Arc?

Tags: rust

I'd like to know how to change the value inside the `Arc` and then make other copies of the `Arc` valid again.

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;
use std::error::Error;
use std::io;
use std::time::Duration;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct El {
  n: i64,
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
  let mut a = Arc::new(El{n: 5});
  let b = Arc::clone(&a);
  let th = thread::spawn(move || {
    println!(r#"Hello, World!"#);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    println!("{:?}", b);
  });
  let mut c = Arc::get_mut(&mut a).unwrap();
  c.n = 10;
  drop(c);
  drop(a);
  th.join().expect("some errors occured");
  Ok(())
}
```

this would results into a panic at the moment when the mutation is already done and pointers are dropped. How to resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are idiomatic ways to send data between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075477/what-are-idiomatic-ways-to-send-data-between-threads)

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios it was not about sending between threads. It was about modifying the pointed data. I got the point of `Arc`, that it is like `std::shared_ptr` without `mutex` or `lock`. But I do not realize the point of `std::sync::RwLock` for necessity of wrapping it with `Arc`. `RwLock` is meaningless without threads, isn't it? 
But it is another question, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to write the contents of an `Arc` in one thread an read it in another. In Rust a value is either shared readable or exclusive writable. Arcs with more than one reference are shared.

You can solve this problem by using internal mutability, e.g. via `Arc<Mutex<El>>` or `Arc<RwLock<El>>`. `Mutex` and `RwLock` ensure the shared/exclusive constraint dynamically by blocking all reads until a write is complete and blocking all writes as long as a read lock exists.

Example:

```
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
  let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(El{n: 5}));
  let b = Arc::clone(&a);
  let th = thread::spawn(move || {
    println!(r#"Hello, World!"#);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    println!("{:?}", b.lock().unwrap());
  });
  a.lock().unwrap().n = 10;
  drop(a);
  th.join().expect("some errors occured");
  Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I simplified the code to make the issue obvious:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct El {
    n: i64,
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Arc::new(El { n: 5 });
    let b = Arc::clone(&a);
    let th = thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
        println!("{:?}", b);
    });
    let _c = Arc::get_mut(&mut a).unwrap();
    th.join().expect("some errors occurred");
}
```

`Arc::get_mut` functions only when its `Arc` parameter is the unique owner: in this situation you can take back the ownership of the data.

In your code, at this line, the spawned thread is still running, and it still holds the shared data through `b`: `a` and `b` share the ownership of the data. You must first ensure that `b` is dropped before taking back the data's ownership (notice the swap of the 2 last lines):

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct El {
    n: i64,
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Arc::new(El { n: 5 });
    let b = Arc::clone(&a);
    let th = thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
        println!("{:?}", b);
    });
    th.join().expect("some errors occurred"); // b has been dropped
    let _c = Arc::get_mut(&mut a).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: No, the interest was in changing the value for another thread.

Comment: @dronte7 Hum, that wasn't clear from the question. You want to transfer some data from the spawned thread to the main thread? Just use a channel.